# How do I get Python to work again on my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am running Raspbian on a Pi 3 that has one job: it runs a clock on a Sense Hat, from Python 3 source code. Recently I found I was unable to run my clock program, which generated an error stack that ended this way:

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1467, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1570, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _compile_bytecode
EOFError: marshal data too short
```

I found a number of possible solutions, none of which worked. Any attempt to uninstall/reinstall  modules with pip3 generated the same error stack. I read instructions to delete all the .pyc files in the Python3 tree and recompile them, but after that any attemtp to load a module just gave me

```
    "defining __gutstate__ cannot be picKled")
```

and I was unable to recreate the .pyc files.

Essentially everything I did that involved touching Python files, whether through apt-get or pip3, failed on some Python error. I can't even remove or purge Python3 itself - I get Python errors that won't let me reinstall Python.

Is there a solution for this? My clock actually runs under Python 2.7, but I'd like to be able to run a supported version of Python if possible. I could reinstall Raspbian but there's no guarantee it wouldn't fail the same way and put me right back where I am.

Comment: I would start with a fresh copy of the OS to make sure you're not hitting some sort of file corruption...and if the problem persists, consider asking over on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com, where you may have better odds of finding someone who has seen the same problem before.

Comment: Thanks. I'll post the question over there. I may try an fsck to check for file corruption but everything looks healthy otherwise.